# why do i get [object Object] when i use jquery trying to retrive some text from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 pages checkuser.php and practice.php.i have a text in checkuser.php that i want to display in practice.php.So i am using jquery in practice.php to look for the id="demo" in checkuser.php display it.However i am not getting the text but rather it displays [object Object].I do not understand where is my mistake.Here are my codes:

practice.php

```
       <script>
        $.get("checkuser.php",function(text){
            alert($(text).find("#demo"));   
          }
        </script>
```

checkuser.php

```
    $sql="SELECT username from accountdetails WHERE username='$uname';";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            echo "<p id="demo">username already exist</p>";
        }else{
            echo "<p id="demo">username does not exists</p>";
        }
```

Comment: `find()` returns a jQuery object, not text ....

Comment: [jQuery find](https://api.jquery.com/find), [jQuery text](https://api.jquery.com/text).  I would very strongly encourage you to get familiar with the API.  This is a very basic question.

Comment: Don't use `alert(object)` it doesn't show you anything - use `console.log(object)` and look in the console.  Still won't give you what you're *expecting* because you're expecting the wrong thing.

Comment: It's just `$(text).text()` in this case, as the outer element is the paragraph.  There is no need to find.

Comment: Your php has a couple of syntax errors, so it's probably not even working. For example `echo "<p id="demo">username already exist</p>";`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i am trying to display this sentence in practice.php  and i thought that by giving it an id it will work

Comment: @TasneemEdoo what I'm saying is that you need to put `'` instead of `"` around what you are `echo`ing, otherwise it wouldn't work, so of course when you apply mamun's answer it's returning empty

Comment: @freedomn-m single quotes around html attributes give me cancer. I'd say it's better to use `'<p id="demo">'`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Mamun's original answer wouldn't have worked as the element with the id was the top level, so it was the equivalent of `$("#demo").find("#demo")`

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you i didnot know that..will try it

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca personal choice - I'm not a php developer so don't know that you can do `echo '<p>'` rather than `echo "<p>"` - but your comment implies that's possible *in php*.

Comment: @freedomn-m indeed it is possible. There's a difference between `'` and `"` in php, mainly the fact that inside `"` you can interpolate variables. And yes, you can use single quotes (or no quotes at all) around html attributes' values, so yes, personal choice, but I grew up with XHTML, that stuff ain't going away from my head :P

Comment: @freedomn-m i tried what you said and it is still not working...it is giving me a blank alert

Comment: What did you try?  My suggestion was to not use `alert`, so getting a blank alert means you didn't try my suggestion...   but anyway, you don't need the `id` - do this: `alert($(text).text());` as suggested by Taplar and in Manun's answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m what i meant was that i tried the thing about quotes and you were right it was giving me an error...but now i am still not getting the text ,i am getting something as object Object..any idea what it means?

Comment: Yes, it means the browser can't handle `alert(object)` - you're getting an object.  Use `console.log(whatever)` and look in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the `text()` from the element. Also, since you are passing the element itself, you should not use `find()`:

```
alert($(text).text());
```

**Please Note:** You also have some syntax error in `echo "<p id="demo">username already exist</p>"` as the string is not properly formatted. You can try the combination of single and double quote like:

```
echo '<p id="demo">username already exist</p>'
```

Comment: by using your method it is giving a blank alert